# Exclusive TFS checkout in PhpStorm

Tags: tfs, version-control, phpstorm

How can I enable exclusive checkout using TFS in PhpStorm?
I would like to have the "Prevent other users from checking out and checking in" option enabled, but I can't find where it is...

Comment: According to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116176 this is the default behavior. Are you sure it doesn't do exclusive checkout at the moment?

Comment: @davidinho Based on my test the option "`Prevent other users from checking out and checking in`" is abailable in Visual Studio when checkout from Server workspace. But no this option in Phpstorm with TFS integration installed.  Please check if this helps: [Handling Modified Without Checkout Files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/handling-modified-without-checkout-files.html)